# Recyclerview checkbox automatically selects another checkbox when clicked

Tags: checkbox, android-volley, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am developing an app that requires that the customer selects all the prices for different problems. I have implemented the recyclerview and inflated the textview and checkbox on the recyclerview but the problem is that when a checkbox is selected it automatically selects another checkbox and if uncheck automatically unchecks the second checkbox.

Here are my code

recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
tools:context="com.example.system2.tranxav.ProblemsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/problem_recycle_view"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProblems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cbProblems"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

myAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
private List<Problems> mDataset;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;
private ProblemListener setProblemListener;
CardView cv;
public void setProblemListener(ProblemListener problemListener){
    this.setProblemListener = problemListener;
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvProblems, tvPrice;
    public Button btnProblem;
    Button btnSubmitProblem;
    CheckBox cbProblems;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProblems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProblems);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        btnSubmitProblem = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProblem);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);

       overrideFonts(context, tvProblems);
    }
}
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensedBold.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void add(List<Problems> itemList){
    mDataset = itemList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void remove(Problems item){
    int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public MyAdapter(Context con, List<Problems> myDataset){
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.context = con;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View itemView;
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //Inflating recycle view item layout
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_content, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);

    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //Inflating header view
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_recycler_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
        //Inflating footer view
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_recycler_footer, parent, false);
        return new FooterViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    try {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {

        HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        headerHolder.tvHeader.setText("Please kindly ask the mechanic what the problem is and check them to continue");

    } else {
        if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {

            final FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            footerHolder.btnSubmitProblem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //  footerHolder.cbProblems.setOnClickListener(null);
                   setProblemListener.onProblemSelected(v, mDataset, position);

                }
            });

        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            ItemViewHolder itemView = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            itemView.tvPrice.setText(mDataset.get(position - 1).getPrice());
            itemView.tvProblems.setText(mDataset.get(position - 1).getProblems());
            itemView.cbProblems.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    mDataset.get(position - 1).setSelected(isChecked);

            });

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size()+2;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if (position == mDataset.size() + 1) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvHeader;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        overrideFonts(context, tvHeader);
    }
}

private class FooterViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    Button btnSubmitProblem;
    CheckBox cbProblems;


    public FooterViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        btnSubmitProblem = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnProblem);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);
    }
}

private class ItemViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvProblems, tvPrice;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProblems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProblems);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);

    }
}

private class CheckboxViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    public CheckboxViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);

    }
}
public interface ProblemListener{
    void onProblemSelected(View view, List<Problems> problem, int position);
}
}
```

oncreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problems);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.problem_recycle_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ProblemsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(ProblemsActivity.this, listProblems);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, PROBLEM_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse(response);
            jsonParse.parseJSON();
            listProblems = jsonParse.getProblems();
            mAdapter.add(listProblems);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Info", "Failed");
            error.printStackTrace();

        }

    });
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(ProblemsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    mAdapter.setProblemListener(new MyAdapter.ProblemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProblemSelected(View view, List<Problems> problem, int position) {

            double price = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < problem.size(); i++) {
                Problems prob = problem.get(i);
                if (prob.isSelected()) {
                    price += Double.parseDouble(prob.getPrice());
                }
            }
            if (price == 0.0){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProblemsActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Select problem solved to proceed");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }else{
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProblemsActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("The Total Amount is " + price);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Proceed >>>",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I just cam online now let me act on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following line

itemView.cbProblems.setChecked(mDataset.get(position-1).isSelected());

before

setOnCheckedChangeListener